# performSegueWithIdentifier on didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, segue

With this code every time user click on any  cell  will perform the segue again and again , I am wondering how could I keep track of the loaded view to keep data when switching views and not an infinite new viewcontroler.

Thanks -

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    [self.navigationController
     performSegueWithIdentifier:@"rep" sender:self];
  } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    [self.navigationController
     performSegueWithIdentifier:@"rep1" sender:self];
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try my other approach first, but if you really need a maintain a pointer to the new view controller you could try this approach.  This should perform the segue once, creating the reference to the view controller which will subsequently be manually pushed into the navigation controller.

Override the view controller methods:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender{

     if(self.myViewController == nil){
          return YES;
     }else{
          [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.myViewController animated:YES]
     }
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

     self.myViewController = (MyViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
     self.myViewController.customVar = 1;  //perform initial customization

}
```

What do I know though, I've never used Storyboards...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an alternative to maintaining a reference to the view controller would be to customize the view controller prior to seque.

Override the view controller method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

     MyViewController *targetController = (MyViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
     targetController.customVar = 1;

}
```

The default implementation of this method does nothing. Your view controller overrides this method when it needs to pass relevant data to the new view controller. The segue object describes the transition and includes references to both view controllers involved in the segue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to take new View controller each and every time for each row unless and until you want it customized. This will make large amount of view controllers on storyboard.

So, Just command drag segue from controller A to B. Example: if A is tableViewController and B is simple VC where you are displaying data of table's row then command drag from whole tableViewController to B. Now this will act as common segue with one identifier only.

So in your code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

//Set your B's label/property etc to cell's data or anything so that it will reflect in B.
B.label = cell.text;   
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Identifier" sender:self];

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can keep the new viewController's pointer. Then next time you can use it like this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:thePointer animated:YES]
```

I very seldom use Storyboard. So I am not sure it will work.